# Meaning of indicator function notation of a random variable

Tags: probability, notation, expectation

My probability text first introduces indicator functions $I_A(\omega)$ as being 1 when $\omega \in A$ and 0 otherwise, where $A$ is an event (a subset of the sample space $\Omega$). So you can say $I_A : \Omega \mapsto \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$.

Later it introduces the notion of random variables and the following notational sugar for comparisons against them:

$$\mathbb{P}(X \in A) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A)) = \mathbb{P}(\lbrace \omega : X(\omega) \in A\rbrace)$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(\lbrace \omega : X(\omega) \leq x\rbrace)$$

Etc. Later in the expectation chapter it has the following identity:

> Let $A$ be an event and let $I_A(x) = 1$ if $x \in A$ and $I_A(x) = 0$
>   if $x \notin A$. Then:
>
> $$\mathbb{E}(I_A(X)) = \int I_A(x)f_X(x)dx = \int_A f_X(x)dx = \mathbb{P}(X \in A)$$

I'm not quite sure how to desugar/interpret $I_A(X)$. The expectation function takes a random variable, and an indicator function as defined at the beginning of the book qualifies as a random variable because it maps outcomes to reals. But here they're passing a random variable into the indicator function, not an outcome, so the types don't match. I thought maybe it could mean this:

$$\mathbb{E}(\lbrace I_A(\omega) : \omega \in X^{-1}(A) \rbrace)$$

But that doesn't work because I know the result must be a random variable (not a set) because that's what $\mathbb{E}$ takes. I would be tempted to interpret the $A$ in $I_A$ to be a subset of the real line rather than an event in the context of the identity, but my text specifically identifies it as an event.

How do I make the types make sense?

Comment: $X$ is a function, $I_A$ is a function, $I_A(X)$ is composite of those functions

Comment: Normally you shouldn't write it in this way, but it means composition, from what can i see that is written in the theorem

Comment: @Adam: if it's just composition, the types don't work. $X(\omega)$ returns a real, which it then tried to pass to $I_A$ -- but $I_A$ doesn't take reals, it takes outcomes.

Comment: @Adam: If $A$ was a subset of the real line, then I'd agree. But they explicitly say it's an event (a set of outcomes).

Comment: The theorem is true and makes perfect sense when $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ ($A$ is measurable/Borel) and $X$ is a continuous variable. They also didn't make any comments about $X$ in the theorem

Comment: @Adam: I think my confusion stems from there only usually being one sample space being discussed. Say $\Omega$ is the possible outcomes of a two coin flips. $X$ maps sequences of flips to reals. In that context a sequence of flips is an outcome. But the $I_A$ in $I_A(X(\omega))$, is taking a real number -- which I guess can be an outcome, but *not in the same sample space*, since a real is not a sequence of coin flips.

Comment: You are right that $A$ should definitely **not** be called "an event" for the notation $I_A(X)$, which can only refer to the event $\{X\in A\}$, to even make sense. It seems you spotted a typo in the text you are reading, congratulations!

Comment: $I_A(X(\omega))$ is also a random variable as a composite of a Borel function ($I_A$ for $A$ measurable) and a random variable ($X$). It's a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The sample space is the same

Comment: @Adam I agree that the composite $I_A(X(\Omega))$ is a random variable mapping in my example sequences of coin flips to a real number, but the $A$ in $I_A$ is not an event in the sequence of coin flip sample space, because $A$ is a subset of the real line, not a sequence of coin flips. If we are to consider $A$ an event, $A$ is an event in a different space.

Comment: @Adam FYI, $I_A(X(\omega))$ is not a random variable but **a number** (a nonnegative integer, even). On the other hand, $I_A(X)$ may be a random variable.